# Where is the SDK path for Android Studio stored in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, android-studio

Is it stored in an .xml file somewhere, or possibly in the registry? I do know it's separate for each user, which is a large part of my problem. The reason I'm looking for this information is that I'd like to make a start-up script that will change the path. The environment I'm working with resets itself back to its original configuration upon a restart. Each time a new user logs in they're required to download and install the SDK as it defaults to being located in a local user folder. If I could change the path with a start-up script and make it part of the default configuration this would save a lot of time for the users.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, the Android SDK folder is stored in:

> `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android`

The `AppData` folder is hidden, so you need to first show hidden folders.